# Error: Permission denied to access property 'className'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I try to add item to a document library I got the following error :

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'className'

in firebug and the item could not be added. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been with Firefox since 2003 as it seems. Please refer the following [issue report](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/ticket/2528488) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2075) one. This is not a SharePoint specific issue.